# Spring Batch Job hangs - concurrent steps and each step using multiple threads

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, parallel-processing, spring-batch

I am using Spring Batch for processing records from database tables using the below scenario:

1. Processing data from 5 tables concurrently using 5 parallel steps
2. Each parallel step has further 5 threads to process records from single table

Here is the summary of job configuration: TestJob -> Parallel Step1 & Step2 -> Step 1 using 2 threads, Step 2 using 2 threads

For Spring Batch tables I tried using SQL Server database, HSQL in memory database but somehow Spring batch stucks when selecting from BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_SEQ
Spring batch trying to INSERT into BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION table so trying to get ID from BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_SEQ table where it hangs.

I am using Spring Boot 2.2.2.RELEASE version. I tried override jobrepository configuration with different create isolation levels but problem always persists.

NOTE:
Everything is working as expected when:

1. Processing concurrent tables at a time and each table processed by single thread
2. Processing single table at a time and single table processed by multiple threads

Any help/pointer to fix the problem is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Har Krishan

Comment: This problem is intermittent, sometimes it is working

Comment: I remember having a similar problem once, not sure how you're setting the isolation level but it's gotta be a certain way to affect the jobrepository https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/job.html#txConfigForJobRepository

Comment: Thanks for pointing to set Isolation level, I tried different isolation levels but problem still persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the sake of others who may be facing the same issue. The issue seems with the configurations of database specific tables and sequences. I tried with SQL Server, still issue persists with the default provided database scripts. Then I tried with Hsql memory database again issue persists. Then I tried using H2 memory database and it worked with that. It also works with MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean.

So you may need to tweak DDL as per database.

Thanks!